# How to get value of <select> at server side in java

Tags: java, html, servlets

I have below code in one of my JSP.

```
<select name="item" id="item">
<option value="val1">One</option>
<option value="val2">Two</option>
<option value="val3">Three</option> 
</select>
```

I know that I can get the value of `<select>` by using request.getParamter("item"). At server side, I received val1/val2/val3 based on the option selected.

But at server side,  I want to get One/Two/Three based on the option selected.

Comment: You can't do that. You can change the ```value``` to what you want on server side. ```<option value="One">One</option>```

Comment: `<option value="One">One</option>`

Comment: No. I can't do that. That's the main problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the text value in server side. If you still want both the `value` and `text` to be read in server side, alter the `value` so that it contains both `text` and `value`

```
<select name="item" id="item">
    <option value="val1:One">One</option>
</select>
```

After you get the value, you can split the value to obtain both.

```
String selected[] = request.getParameter("item").split(":");
String selectedValue = selected[0];
String selectedText = selected[1];
```

Comment: I know that I can get by manipulating value attribute of <option>.But I can't change the value of <option> because It comes from the DB as well from the request.

Comment: Then there is no option other than getting the ```value``` and querying the text from database

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help.